# In Vuejs3 How to disable or close modal on click of close Icon in CoreUI

Tags: vuejs3, core-ui

```
     *** CORE UI ***
```

As you can see my below code i am trying to close the modal using close icon. when I am writing some data on modal page and after that without submit I am closing that modal the data remain same. The page dose not get refresh. The Modal comes back with old data when reopen.

```
 <CModal :show.sync="modalAdd" :centered="true" >
  <CForm>
  <CRow>
    <CCol>
      <CInput
        label="Name"
        v-model="Name"
      />
    </CCol>
  </CRow>
  <CRow>
    <CCol> Image
      <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        ref="file"
        @change="onFileUpload()"

      />
    </CCol>
  </CRow>
  <CRow>
    <CCol>
      <CTextarea label="Short_Description"  verticle rows="3" v-model="short_description"/>
    </CCol>
  </CRow>
  <CRow>
    <CCol>
      <CTextarea label="Long_Description"  verticle rows="5" v-model="long_description" required/>
    </CCol>
  </CRow>
  </CForm>
  <template #footer>
    <CButton @click="modalAdd = false" size="sm" color="danger">Cancel</CButton>
    <CButton @click="addTherapyCategory" size="sm" color="success">Save</CButton>
  </template>
</CModal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing the modal doesn't reset the `v-model` values, so the next time you show it, they'll still be what they were when you closed the modal.  You can call a reset method on close:

```html
<CButton @click="reset" size="sm" color="danger">Cancel</CButton>
```

```js
methods: {
  reset() {
    this.modalAdd = false;
    this.Name = '';
    this.short_description = '';
    this.long_description = '';
  }
}
```